# Java Selenium ChromeDriver, WebDriver, как отключить картинки?

Tags: java, изображения, selenium

Помогите пож-та отключить картинки при загрузке страницы, в интернете почти везде пишут, что надо прописать это:

```
prefs.put("profile.managed_default_content_settings.images", 2);
```

но это не помогает.

Чего только не пробовал, ничего не помогает, что я делаю не так?

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\chromedriver.exe");

        Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<>();

        prefs.put("profile.managed_default_content_settings.images", 2);

        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

        options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);


        options.addArguments("--headless", "--disable-gpu", "--blink-settings=imagesEnabled=false");
        options.addArguments("--blink-settings=imagesEnabled=false");

        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

        driver.get("https://yandex.ru/");
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        driver.quit();

    }
}
```

Comment: Ну хоть кто ни будь помогите разобраться с проблемой...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена!
Дело было в старой версии зависимости selenium

Решение:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
</dependency>


import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
 
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
 
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\chromedriver.exe");
 
        Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<>();
        prefs.put("profile.managed_default_content_settings.images", 2);
 
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
 
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
 
        driver.get("https://yandex.ru/");
        Thread.sleep(15000);
 
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```